# How to get child user stories from parent (using filter in snapshotstore) using the sdk api js

Tags: filter, rally, user-stories

Using the REST API I can simply use the following [link](https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/HierarchicalRequirement/%7BObjectId%7D/Children) to get all child stories for a specific object:

How can I get the same result using the Rally SDK Api JS (without Rest)?
Is there a filter that can be used to get the same results in a (snapshot)store?

Answer (score 1):

There are quite a few examples of how to do this in JavaScript in the help manuals. When you are logged in to Agile Central, click on your avatar and go to Help. In the search box enter "SDK".

One of the entries returned should be titled "Agile Central App SDK 2.1 Docs". Click on that and then click on "Examples" or "Guides"

Children are considered a "Collection" in the documentation.
 There is a section on handling Collections under "Working with WSAPI" in the guides.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to add a store filter much like you would do a regular wsapi store.  The one difference is that in Lookback API objects are referenced by object id rather than ref.

Filtering guide: https://help.rallydev.com/apps/2.1/doc/#!/guide/lookback_api-section-filtering

Example:

```
filters: [{
    property: 'Parent',
    value: 12345
}]
```